# Filling Textboxes in Python via Mechanize Without Forms

Tags: python, input, mechanize

I'm trying to fill textboxes in [this](http://www.kentkartim.com/bakiyesorgula.php) site but mechanize can't find any form.Therefore I can't do anything on thoose textboxes cause they're in non-exists form.

I tried so different solutions but i failed.Here is my code :

```
import mechanize

def kota():
 br = mechanize.Browser()
 br.open("http://www.kentkartim.com/bakiyesorgula.php")
 a = br.select_form(nr=0)
 print(a)
```

With this I get this result :

```
mechanize._mechanize.FormNotFoundError: no form matching nr 0
```

I'm thinking that the reason of the result is the webpage using javascript. I need to fill the textboxes and submit them.

Comment: The form isn't loaded via AJAX or injected using JS, however I think your problem may be that on viewing the page for the first time, the site presents a grid of images instead of the form.

Comment: what do you suggest to solve this complication :S Should i keep using Mechanize or try another solutions like Selenium ?

Comment: Mechanize can probably do it (although I've never used it), but you will need to get it to accept and store cookies or whatever else the site uses to store whether you've seen their landing page or not.